# Pass objects from referenced managed dll to a C++/CLI wrapper

Tags: dll, c++-cli, wrapper

So, I'm a writing a C++/CLI wrapper and I would like it to interact with objects from a referenced, managed (C#) dll. More specifically, in my C++/CLI project, I would like to have classes like this:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
    public:
        void InputPoints(array<Point3d^>^ ptsIn);
};
```

Where, "Point3d" is an object from the referenced, managed dll - call it "MyGeometryDLL.dll". This compiles without any problems, however when I use the wrapper in a C# project (that also references "MyGeometryDLL.dll") , I can't pass Point3d directly to the wrapper, i.e., intellisense detects:

```
void MyClass.InputPoints(ValueType[] ptsIn);
```

How would I pass Point3d directly to the wrapper?

Comment: The problem is with Point3d, it is not a managed type.  You'll need to declare, say, `public value class Point3d { /* ... */ };`.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks! However, now my C# project expects a return type of "MyWrapper.Point3d[]". I'm still not clear on how to cast this as MyGeometryDLL.Point3d.

Comment: If you do `public value class`, that makes a value type, so you'll need to remove the `^` on the `Point3d`: `array<Point3d>^`. If you want it to be a reference type, use `public ref class`, and keep the `^`.

Comment: You cannot cast a managed struct to an unmanaged one, they don't normally have the same layout.  You can use Marshal::StructureToPtr() to make the conversion but that tends to be overkill on a simple struct.  Just assigning the struct members is the simpler way.  This does tend to invoke the "really???" exclamation.  Yes, really.  Structure layout is a pretty nasty implementation detail.

Comment: Btw, David does bring up a valid point, if Point3d is actually a managed struct then you must omit the ^ hat.  It should only be used on reference types.

Comment: Got it! I also had to make sure to define "public value class Point3d" in the namespace "MyGeometryDLL". Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So class `Point3d` is already defined in a C# DLL, correct? In that case, I think it may be an issue of carats.

If it's declared in C# as `public struct Point3d`, then it's a value type, not a reference type. That means that whenever you use it in C++/CLI, you don't use the `^`, and you don't call `gcnew`. If that's the case, then you need to change the method declaration to this:

```
void InputPoints(array<Point3d>^ ptsIn); // No carat on Point3d
```

The reason that C# sees this as `ValueType[]` is because `Point3d^` is a legal type in C++/CLI, but it doesn't exist in C#. A general `ValueType` is the closest thing, so that's what C# sees.